# How to use CDN of Highchart map-collection insted of npm package in angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, cdn, angular9

How to use CDN of Highchart map-collection insted of npm package in angular 9?
I have used map-collection NPM package for rendering highcharts map but that package taking too much size in project.

Comment: @BrownPaul do you have any stackblitz demo

Comment: Try this approach: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/how-to-create-custom-highcharts-files